# Magento 2.4 "Bad Request 400 Exception" when using Elasticsearch

Tags: magento2, error, search, elasticsearch, exception

I've recently upgraded my Magento version 2.4 and set Elasticsearch as the catalog search option, testing the connection gives a success message but when I try to search on the site itself I get an error message:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception): {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [huuid]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v18","node":"r9_ZsNBiTqiP7FJDre9MmA","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [huuid]"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [huuid]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [huuid]"}}},"status":400}

Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception): {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [huuid]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2_product_1_v18","node":"r9_ZsNBiTqiP7FJDre9MmA","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [huuid]"}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [huuid]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"no mapping found for field [huuid]"}}},"status":400}
<pre>#1 Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(array('transfer_stats' => array('url' => 'http://localhost...', 'content_type' => 'application/json...', 'http_code' => 400, 'header_size' => 241, 'request_size' => 9646, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_resul...' => 0, 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 0.001344, 'namelookup_time' => 2.0E-5, 'connect_time' => 2.0E-5, 'pretransfer_time' => 5.4E-5, 'size_upload' => 9421, 'size_download' => 605, 'speed_download' => 605000, 'speed_upload' => 9421000, 'download_content...' => 605, 'upload_content_l...' => 9421, 'starttransfer_ti...' => 0.001326, 'redirect_time' => 0, 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '::1', 'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => 9200, 'local_ip' => '::1', 'local_port' => 38568, 'http_version' => 2, 'protocol' => 1, 'ssl_verifyresult' => 0, 'scheme' => 'HTTP', 'error' => '', 'errno' => 0), 'curl' => array('error' => '', 'errno' => 0), 'effective_url' => 'http://localhost...', 'headers' => array('Warning' => array('299 Elasticsearc...'), 'content-type' => array('application/json...'), 'content-length' => array(605)), 'version' => 1.1, 'status' => 400, 'reason' => 'Bad Request', 'body' => '{"error":{"root_...')) called at [vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:28]
#2 React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(&Closure#000000002259009b0000000036d4a3c1#, NULL, NULL) called at [vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php:55]
#3 GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureValue->then(&Closure#000000002259009b0000000036d4a3c1#, NULL, NULL) called at [vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Core.php:341]
#4 GuzzleHttp\Ring\Core::proxy(&GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureArray#00000000225900980000000036d4a3c1#, &Closure#000000002259009b0000000036d4a3c1#) called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:329]
#5 Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(array('http_method' => 'POST', 'scheme' => 'http', 'uri' => '/magento2_produc...', 'body' => '{"suggest":{"tex...', 'headers' => array('Host' => array('localhost'), 'Content-Type' => array('application/json'), 'Accept' => array('application/json'), 'User-Agent' => array('elasticsearch-ph...')), 'client' => array('port_in_header' => false, 'curl' => array(9200))), &Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection#00000000225901600000000036d4a3c1#, &Elasticsearch\Transport#00000000225901670000000036d4a3c1#, array()) called at [vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:227]
```

Looking at the developer console it also gives the a 500 error:

> GET https://websitename.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=%23Searchterm 500

I'm not entirely sure what is causing this problem. If anyone can offer any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure: `Elastic search is running, configured with your server`

Comment: Running "curl localhost:9200" returns  version number 7.10.2. Running "ps aux | grep elasticsearch" returns values for elasticsearch and testing the connection is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was due to the SKU product attribute not being searchable.

I have now set modified the settings so that the value for searchable is "Yes" and this seems to have resolved this issue.